# Extending django.contrib.auth.User model

Tags: python, django

I'm using django.contrib.auth and I have a working login/registration system, however I want to extend my User model to have street address and phone number for registration purposes only, and I'm not sure how can I do that properly. What I have done works but feels wrong and I would like to know a proper way to do this.

I created `accounts` app and in `models.py` I have this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

...then I registered that in `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User

admin.site.register(User)
```

...then in `settings.py` I added this line:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'
```

...and wherever I used `django.contrib.auth.User`, now I use `accounts.models.User`.

As I said, this works however it somehow feels wrong and it easily could be as this is my first time extending the User model. Why I think this is wrong? For one, `Users` has disappeared in admin from "Authentication and Authorization" and is instead under "Accounts" (as expected).

How can I accomplish this in a proper way?

@EDIT:

Here is my register form:

```
from django import forms
from accounts.models import User


class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repeat password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'email',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'address',
            'address_number',
            'phone'
        )

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords do not match.')
        return cd['password2']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                'Please use another e-mail, that is already taken.')
        return email
```

Comment: rather that override the base user model, consider using a user `Profile` model with a one-to-one mapping to a `User`

Comment: @Tobey how would I then change my form code? I updated the question.

Comment: This is exactly as documented. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You've done everything correct [as specified in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). The one thing you could do differently is inherit from `django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm` and just override the fields meta option.

Comment: Adding a `Profile` instead of extending `User` will lead to less coupled code. Another apps will continue to use vanilla `User` class